# White space when using 100% Width

Tags: html, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace

A friend and I are working on a website, but for some reason there is still white space when I use 100% width. How can I fix this? These are the main css elements

```
#info_container{
height:100%;
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
padding-top:3%;
background-color:#D3D3D3;
}

#main_header {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#2a2a2a, #545454);
text-align: center;
align-items: center;
vertical-align: middle;
position: absolute;
width:100%;
height:8%;
margin:-1em;
position:fixed;
display: table;
width: 100%;
table-layout: fixed;
/* For cells of equal size */
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jvidaurri77/ksk1droL/19/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First best practice is to put universal selector `* { padding: 0; margin: 0;}`
to avoid the margins and paddings overflow.

I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksk1droL/28/)

Changes to your CSS

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

#main_header {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#2a2a2a, #545454);
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    /* For cells of equal size */
}
#main_header a {
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#567aa9;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding:.5%;
}
a span {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#878787;
    font-size:55px;
    top: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    left:50%;
}
.a1:hover {
    color:#bababa;
}
.a2:hover{
    color:#bababa;
}
.a3:hover{
    color:#bababa;
}
.a4:hover{
    color:#bababa;
}
#info_container{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:7%;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    font-size: 1em;
}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
    html {
        font-size: 70%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    html {
        font-size: 80%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
    html {
        font-size: 120%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    html {
        font-size: 200%;
    }
}
#info_container{
    height: 100px; // changed this from 100%;
    width:100%;
    padding-top: 3%; // removed
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#D3D3D3;
}
```

EDIT: UPDATED THE FIDDLE

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple fix to this. You have a background color on your text which goes on the whole line, so to make it only on the text area in your info container, simply put that text into a span class. Now just remove that background color from the original class and put it into your span! You can give a class to the span if you will put it into another css file, but I have just put it directly into the html here.

```
<p><span style="background-color:red;">Hello World</span></p>
```